# Customize permalink when creating a post

Tags: custom-post-types, plugin-development, custom-field, permalinks

I have a custom post type named houses. Inside my custom post type I have several custom fields which I created using ACF.

What I need to do is to change the permalink when I create a new post.

I would like to use the **code** and **title** fields to customize the permalink:

```
//code + post title
4563312-house-example-1
```

I'm developing a plugin which controls everything.

Is there a way to intermediate the creation of a post to update its permalink?

Thanks.

Comment: when the post is created, the custom fields are empty then you want to custom the permalink when the post is saved ?

Comment: You were right @mmm, I had to use a hook called save_post, in this way I was capable to get the custom field value. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The example that Cedon gave me to me, I could reach what I needed, with a few changes.

Using wp_insert_post_data, I couldn't get the custom field value, and to achieve that, I had to use another action, **save_post** instead.

```
function rci_custom_permalink($post_id) {
  $post = get_post($post_id);
  if($post->post_type !== 'houses') return;

  $code = get_field('code', $post_id);
  $post_name = sanitize_title($post->post_title);
  $permalink = $code . '-' . $post_name;

  // remove the action to not enter in a loop
  remove_action('save_post', 'rci_custom_permalink');

  // perform the update
  wp_update_post(array('ID' => $post_id, 'post_name' => $permalink));

  // add the action again
  add_action('save_post', 'rci_custom_permalink');
} 

add_action('save_post', 'rci_custom_permalink');
```

PS: Since all these fields are required, I didn't need to check if they are empty or not.

For reference about save_post action:
[Plugin API/Action Reference/save post](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Action_Reference/save_post)

Answer (score 3):

This can be done using the `wp_insert_post_data` hook.

```
function house_post_slug( $data ) {
    if ( $data['post_type'] == 'houses' ) {
       $permalink = '';

       if ( isset ( $_POST['ACF Code Field'] ) ) {
          $permalink = $_POST['ACF Code Field'];
       }

       if ( isset ( $_POST['post_title'] ) ) {
          $permalink .= '-' . $_POST['post_title'];
       }

       $data['post_name'] = sanitize_title( $permalink )
    }

    error_log( '=== Filter $data ===');
    error_log( print_r($data, true) );
    return $data;

}
add_filter( 'wp_insert_post_data', 'house_post_slug' );
```

So what this filter will do is intercept `$data` from WordPress, check to see if the `post_type` field is for your custom post type so it will only fire for that particular CPT.

Then it will check to see if the ACF Code Field is set. And if it is, then it will set `$permalink to that value.

I have not used ACF so I am not sure what the structure they use is. You can see a dump of this by adding:

```
error_log( print_r ( $_POST, true ) );
```

Next, it will check and see if the `post_title` key is set. If so, then it will append `-` and whatever the value of `post_title` is.

Finally, we set the `post_name` key in `$data` to a sanitized version of `$permalink` and then return that.

I put in two `error_log()` statements so you can see the dump of `$data` for diagnostic purposes.